# What does it mean to use Substitution Jutsu?

Tags: naruto-ultimate-ninja

I'm stuck on the the mission "Sakura's Training" (C-rank I think) where one of the conditions is to use the Substitution Jutsu more than 6 times. What does it mean by that? Does it mean use the item Substitution Justu more than six times, or obtain the item Substitution Jutsu more than 6 times, or block when an enemy attacks you and teleport behind them, or do additional blows and teleport behind them when they try to strike you, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From doing research into this, I have determined the [Substitution Jutsu](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/918651-naruto-ultimate-ninja/faqs/46768) the game refers to is where you teleport just as your opponent tries to hit you.

> Substitution Jutsu: Hit the L2 or R2 button just before you enemy hits you.

Note: The link contains spoilers.

Answer (score 0):

You press R2 right before something -- or someone -- hits you, causing you to substitute your body with a wood log and teleport behind the enemy. However it should be noted that once you weave a substitution jutsu your enemy can immediately counter with another substitution jutsu. But it is seriously all about timing it. You have to watch every attack that your opponent throws at you and try to avoid everything.